# How to update component when clicking on that specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a todo app and for editing tasks I want to make an edit mode. I have a title of the task and once you click on that, it expands to the details of that specific task (Collapse from MUI). I want to enable that once I click on the text of one of the details of the tasks it should enter in an edit mode.

I have a ternary operator for this approach if not inEditMode (handled by state), text appears however once I click on that page becomes blank and I have to refresh for turning back.

All of the examples for this functionality is being solved by seperating the edit mode by using modal components or another input field apart from that task detail component. But its the easy way to do it and not good for UX.

For example,

```
function handleSubmit() {
  setInEditMode(false)

}

{
 inEditMode 
   ? <p> {taskDetail} </p>
   : <input component  
       onSubmit={setInEditMode(false)} or onSubmit={setInEditMode(false)}
       textRef={someRefvariable} // useRef is used for here
       onChange={setTaskDetail(someRefVariable}
     />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ternary operator contain few problems. Try solve them and it might help, if not, provide errors from console.

```
{
 inEditMode 
   ? <p> {taskDetail} </p>
   : <input component // That is actually a basic input with unknown prop 'component', maybe you mean InputComponent instead of 'input component' 

       //the next line have no comment, so `or onSubmit={setInEditMode(false)} ` this will lead to error
       onSubmit={setInEditMode(false)} or onSubmit={setInEditMode(false)} 
       textRef={someRefvariable}

       // On the next line and in `onSubmit` you immediately run functions instead of passing them, so when your component is rendered, it will run those functions
       onChange={setTaskDetail(someRefVariable}
     />
}
```

Hope it helps